# AWS Autogenerated Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-simple-email-service

I hired out the development of an app/database project and received something that works, but not as I requested.

When a user downloads the app and creates an account, an AWS autogenerated email goes out with a temporary password and a prompt to change that password.

The problem is that the email contains two other company names!  The developers must have used a template and forgot to change the text.  I need some guidance on finding the AWS service that sends the email so I can change the outgoing message.  Would this be a SES function?  Lambda?  I'm at a loss.

I've asked the developers for pointers to the right AWS services but they won't acknowledge my emails.  It's on me to fix this and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Seems like they're using AWS Cognito

Comment: I went to Cognito and I can manage user or identity pools.  Both are empty as ask me to create users.

Comment: Can you attach the email template in the question

Comment: I don't have it.  I need to find it first.  Is is possible that all of this is driven by some other service?  AWS stores our DB and we use a few other AWS services, but is there another common service that could do this?

Comment: Check SNS or IAM

Comment: Emails must definitely be going through SES if it is AWS. You should start from there and then trace back the service using SES